# 'napa' is not recognised in angular

Tags: angular, visual-studio, .net-core

I faced problem to publish an angular project using **Visual Studio 2017**. That time **npm install ** time this type of error is show up.

[image]

Please refer **Above** image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try- `npm install napa --save-dev`

check this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/napa

Comment: That time give dependency errors. like `npm WARN @agm/core@1.0.0-beta.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

Comment: You need to install that peer dependencies.
You can use npm-install-peers to find and install required peer dependencies.

npm install -g npm-install-peers and

npm-install-peers.

If you are getting this error after updating any package's version then remove node_modules directory and reinstall packages by npm install or npm cache clean and npm install .